# Consulta MySQL con Ajax PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Necesito hacer un query a mi base de datos desde un boton, y he tenido problemas con eso.

Tengo un `<button>` o un `<a>` o un `<input type>` y quiero que mediante el `onclick` me cambie un registro, es decir, que si presiono el botón el campo **"estado"** de mi tabla pase de **"disponible"** a **"ocupado"**.

He estado viendo que se puede hacer con `ajax` el cual ocupa tu función en `PHP` pero no funciona

```
<input type="submit" onclick="accion();">

<script>
 function accion()
{

$.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url: 'boton.php',
        success:function (){

            alert('Bien');
       },
       error:function (){

        alert("mal");
       }
     });

}
  </script>
```

y esto tengo en "boton.php"

```
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sm");
  mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Lunes set EstadoL="Ocupado";");

  ?>
```

Ojala puedan ayudarme, si me despliega el `alert` pero hasta ahí

Comment: `myslqli_query` debería ser: `mysqli_query `

Comment: Es verdad, corregido y aun así nada :/

Comment: Tienes que comprobar posibles errores en la consola (js) y en la conexión/query (php)... [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) puedes ver como captar posibles errores

Comment: Para que te sea mas fácil descubrir problemas relacionados con AJAX, al menos mientras estas desarrollando, deberías obtener lo que se genera en la salida del archivo php. Por ejemplo cambiar `success:function (){alert('Bien');},` por `success:function (respuesta){console.log(respuesta);},`, de esta manera veras lo que ocurre en el archivo php en la consola.

Comment: @EduardoCervantes El código que has puesto es todo lo que tienes?? Por favor trata de añadir todo el código es difícil tener que adivinar cual es el error, falta más código, hasta ahora el código que has publicado solo muestra las `alert` si la ruta del archivo `boton.php` es la correcta o incorrecta, de eso depende la `alert` del mensaje `bien` o `mal`.

Comment: A parte de [esta respuesta proporcionada por Juan Pinto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/123768/18608), ¿La tabla se llama `Lunes` y el campo `EstadoL`? ¿Podrías compartir la definición usando un `DESCRIBE CREATE TABLE Lunes`? ¿El `alert` que te sale es de que todo va correcto o de que falla? ¿Qué deseas hacer tras ocupar el día?

Answer (score 2):

Prueba cambiando:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Lunes set EstadoL="Ocupado";");
```

con:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Lunes set EstadoL='Ocupado';");
```

Comment: El problema sigue :/

Comment: Y si mandas una respuesta con un "echo"? Y recíbelo en la función de tu ajax. Así verás si se ejecutó correctamente la consulta.

Answer (score 2):

imprime lo que te devuelve la petición, para eso tendrás que
regresa un mensaje de tu archivo boton.php

este seria tu función

```
   $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'boton.php',
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                    alert(response);
                  },
                  error: function(xhr, type, exception) {
                  alert("error ajax")
                 }
             });
```

y en tu archivo boton.php regresa un mensaje para saber si existe algún error

```
$result="";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sm");
// Check connection
if (!$con)
{
   $result="Failed to connect to MySQL ";
}
else{
  // 
  if (mysqli_query($con," UPDATE Lunes set EstadoL='Ocupado';")) {
     $result="Actualizado correctamente";
  } else {
     $result="Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
}

echo $result;
```

no olvides incluir jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```